# Is there a category whose morphisms between A and B are diagrams of type "A -> B -> A"?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading about spans in Category theory, which denote categories with finite colimits whose morphisms are equivalence classes of diagrams "A <- X -> B".
There's also their categorical dual, cospans, with the arrows reversed.

Is there a construction where arrows would form a sequence A -> B -> A?

Composition of Hom(A, B) (elements are A -> B -> A) and Hom(B, C) (elements are B -> C -> B) would then yield a an element of Hom(A, C) which is a diagram A -> B -> C -> B -> A.

It seems this is a category (associativity and identity hold), but I'm not sure has it been discussed in the literature somewhere.

I'm not even sure how to search for something like this.

Comment: Equivalent how?  By coherent objectwise isos?

Comment: Actually, I think the "equivalence classes" isn't needed in the title. I thought the composition in this category was associative only up to isomorphism at one point, but it seems it's _strictly_ associative and unital.
Does this answer your question?

Comment: It seems to me that your construction is isomorphic to the full subcategory of the product $C\times C^{op}$ defined by objects with the two components equal.

Comment: I think it's also the functor category $\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{I}$ where $\mathcal{I}$ is the little category $0 \stackrel{\alpha}{\to} 1 \stackrel{\beta}{\to} 0$.

Comment: @Randall The objects of your $C^{\mathcal I}$ would be the morphisms of the category in the question.

Comment: Ah, you are correct.  I forgot OP was retaining the objects.

Comment: Thank you! Both of the formulations are interesting and something along the lines of what I'm looking for